# XCode Identation/Bracket Preferences

Tags: xcode, indentation, brackets

I'm trying to adjust XCode 4's preferences to automatically create this indentation style. Might be uncommon, but I like it. VS.Net has settings for this, any ideas on how to achieve the same in XCode?

```
- (Tile*)initWithValues:(int) x andY:(int) y andOffX:(int) ox andOffY:(int) oy
    {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
        {
        posX = x;
        posY = y;
        offsetX = ox;
        offsetY = oy;
        return self;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a little bit of this through the Text Editing pane of Xcode's preferences, but to do anything interesting you'll need to use `defaults` from the command line. Apple has documentation devoted to customizing Xcode behaviors with `defaults`:

[Source Code Formatting User Defaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005535-CH3-SW57)